# Algorithm sub-numbering

Tags: captions, algorithms

I have the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[tb]{\textwidth}    \centering \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
        \null
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{New algorithm 1a}\label{a:1a}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]

                \State\Return
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill\vline\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
        \null
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{New algorithm 1b}\label{a:1b}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]

                \State\Return
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

What I need is to rename the left algorithm number to 1(a) and the right to 1(b). After that, I have another algorithm in full page width, for which I need algorithm number 2.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is similar to `subequations` in `amsmath`: inside `subalgorithms` the algorithms will be numbered `<main><letter>`, independently of the final formatting.

I added a vertical adjustment for getting a better rule between the two objects (but I can't see a need for the rule).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcounter{savealgorithm}
\newenvironment{subalgorithms}
 {%
  \stepcounter{algorithm}%
  \edef\currentthealgorithm{\thealgorithm}%
  \setcounter{savealgorithm}{\value{algorithm}}%
  \setcounter{algorithm}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\currentthealgorithm\alph{algorithm}}%
 }
 {%
  \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{savealgorithm}}%
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{subalgorithms}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{New algorithm 1a}\label{a:1a}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State\Return
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vline\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{New algorithm 1b}\label{a:1b}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State\Return
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{subalgorithms}
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{New algorithm 2}\label{a:2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State\Return
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're placing these inside a group - a `minipage` - you can locally redefine the display of the `algorithm` counter to denote your sub-numbering. While the counter in the background will still be incremented as usual, `\label`s will use `\thealgorithm` and correctly reference the algorithms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
  \stepcounter{algorithm}% Increment algorithm counter
  \edef\algbasenum{\thealgorithm}% Store current value
  % Local redefinition...
  \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\algbasenum (a)}% Update algorithm number display
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \null
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{New algorithm 1a}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State\Return
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill\vline\hfill
  % Local redefinition...
  \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\algbasenum (b)}% Update algorithm number display
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
    \null
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \caption{New algorithm 1b}
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State\Return
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \addtocounter{algorithm}{-2}% Restore algorithm counter
\end{minipage}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{New algorithm 2}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State\Return
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Since the redefinition of `\thealgorithm` is local to the group, it'll restore to its default - `\arabic{algorithm}` - at `\end{minipage}`.

Answer (score 2):

One could use the `\ContinuedFloat` feature of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption} % - This line added
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[tb]{\textwidth}    \centering \setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\alph{ContinuedFloat}} % - This line added
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
        \null
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \ContinuedFloat* % - This line added
            \caption{New algorithm 1a}\label{a:1a}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]

                \State\Return
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill\vline\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
        \null
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \ContinuedFloat % - This line added
            \caption{New algorithm 1b}\label{a:1b}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]

                \State\Return
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{New algorithm 2}\label{a:2}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \State\Return
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, originally based on [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) and [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s answers.

This is a nest-able environment that will append a counter to the current figure name for any algorithms defined inside of it.

```latex
\newenvironment{subalgorithms}{%
    \edef\lastAlgorithm{\value{algorithm}}% Store the current algorithm counter (parent algorithm counter)
    \edef\parentAlgorithm{\thealgorithm}% Store the value of \thealgorithm which is the entire algorithm number
    \setcounter{algorithm}{0}% Reset algorithm counter (to count subalgorithms)
    % Redefine \thealgorithm to include the parent algorithm number
    \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\parentAlgorithm.\arabic{algorithm}}%
}{%
    \edef\previousAlgorithm{\value{algorithm}}% Store the 'last breadcrumb' algorithm counter
    \setcounter{algorithm}{\lastAlgorithm}% Restore algorithm counter (to parent algorithm counter)
    \addtocounter{algorithm}{-\previousAlgorithm}% Subtract subalgorithm count from parent algorithm count
    \addtocounter{algorithm}{1}% But add 1 to account for the parent algorithm
}
```

---

**Example Usage**

[image: Example LaTeX rendering of code]

```latex
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The SAT Function}
\end{algorithm}

\subsubsection{The Auxiliary Functions}
\begin{subalgorithms}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
        \label{alg:sat_ex}\label{alg:the-sat-ex-algorithm-for-ctl}
        \index{SAT!Formal Definition for CTL!$SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{subalgorithms}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
        \end{algorithm}

        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{subalgorithms}
\end{subalgorithms}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The $SAT_{EX}$ Auxiliary Function for SAT}
\end{algorithm}
```

---

**Note that** figures will inherit the 'parent' figure number (i.e., the leading portion of the figure number) from any algorithms preceding the subalgorithms environment. So, if you were to place multiple `subalgorithms` environments after each other, all but the first would repeat numbering.

This is a design choice to allow you to simply place a `subalgorithms` environment after an algorithm to add additional `subalgorithms` for it.

If you wish to place multiple `subalgorithms` environments after one-another, simply use `\addtocounter{algorithm}{1}` between the environments to increment the 'parent' algorithm counter.